# why use white space around %*c

Tags: c, input, output, scanf

This is the first code:

```
int a, b;
scanf("%d%*c%d",&a,&b);
printf("%d %d",a,b);
```

if I input

```
4
5
```

it prints

```
4 5
```

This is the second code:

```
int a,b;

scanf("%d %*c %d",&a,&b);

printf("%d %d",a,b);
```

if is input

```
4
5
6
```

it prints

```
4 6
```

why `%*c` skips a character only if it is surrounded by a white space

Comment: What EXACTLY did you input?  Did it actually contain commas?

Comment: no it didn't contained the commas

Comment: I think that a comment saying that [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21061400/771663) is off-topic is not an encouragement to repost the same question again and again...

Comment: Read [scanf Format Specification Syntax](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm) : `*` == `Assignment Supression.  This modifier causes the corresponding input to be matched and converted, but not assigned (no matching argument is needed).`

Comment: but Grijesh I want to know why white space is needed around %*c

Comment: @user3180902 from [scanf manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) Because `A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.` and  `%*c` will not skips white spaces

Answer (score 1):

You are not inputting quite what you think you are: think that the two input sequences are `4` then `5` and `4` then `5` then `6` - what you are inputting is `4` *newline* `5` and `4` *newline* `5` *newline* `6` - the spaces in your `scanf` can match spaces or newlines.

Note that you should also test with:

```
4 5
4,5
4?5
4 5 6
4,5,6
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why use white-space around `"%*c"`?

A: The white-space in `" %*c"` is a `scanf()` directive that skips white-spaces (0 or more) during the scan thus preventing `"%*c"` from itself reading a white-space.  Without the leading white-space, `"%*c"` will scan *any* 1 `char`, white-space or not.  The trailing white-space in `"%*c "` has no effect at all on what `"%*c"` already did.  The trailing white-space directive simple skips subsequent white-spaces.

---

White-space in a format is not *needed* around `"%*c"`, it depends on the coding goal.

Most specifiers, like `"%d"`, `"%f"`, `"%s"` skip leading white-spaces.  (White-space being `' '`, `'\n'`, `'\t'`, etc.  see `isspace()`).

Simply having a format directive `" "` or `"\n"` also skips white-spaces.

3 specifiers `"%c"`, `"%n"` and `"%[scanset]"` do *not* skip leading white-spaces.

Since many programmers want `scanf()` to skip leading white-spaces before a `"%c"` a **preceding white-space is needed** as in `" %c"`.

Note: `"%d %*c %d"` will scan the same as `"%d %*c%d"`.